# What does the modulus symbol do here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulo, modulus

I understand the use of the modulus in regularity, but does it have multiple uses? 
For instance, I saw this:

```
print "key is '%s'" %keydecrypt
print "encrypted text is '%s'" %cipher
```

I don't understand what the modulus in the strings and then the modulus next to the variables are necessarily doing.
-->is it a way to substitute values into string?

Comment: It's used for string formatting. You might want to look that up.

Comment: Yes, it is.  It's similar to `printf`-style formats in `C` code. The `%s` code means "apply `str()` to the argument, and insert the result in place of `%s`".

Answer (score 2):

It is a text placeholder, In this case it substitutes what's in `keydecrypt` and `cipher` to `%s` in the string. So if `keydecrypt` and `cipher` were `abc`, output would be:

```
key is 'abc'
encrypted text is 'abc'
```

However the new [`string.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function is more suitable as it is more explicit:

```
print "key is '{0}'" .format(keydecrypt)
print "encrypted text is '{0}'".format(cipher)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. It substitutes in the variables. It also can do more in regards to formatting.**

Also, You don't need the apostrophes.

And you can also use multiple variables by passing a list. i.e;

```
print "key is: %s, encrypted text is: %s" % (keydecrypt, cipher)
```

And there are different types besides %s, like %r;

```
try:
    something
except Exception, e:
    print "The formatted Exception is: %r" % ex
```

It is generally better to use this than the other way;

```
print "This is my var: " + variable
```

*Remember, in python, everything is an object.*